# How to generate a Cumulative Normal Distribution in PHP

Tags: php, math

Can anyone tell me how to get the equivalent of the Excel (NORMDIST (TRUE)) function in PHP?

I have tried the PECL stats package (stats_dens_normal) but this appears to produce the probability mass function (equivalent to using NORMDIST in Excel with cumulative set to FALSE).

So in summary, I want to use PHP to get the equivalent of Excel's NORMDIST(x, mean, standard_dev TRUE).

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: I'm not going to post the entire PHP code here, because it's quite substantial; but take a look at the functions.php file in [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) which implements NORMDIST (both cumulative and non-cumulative)

Answer (score 12):

There's a php method for approximate cumulative normal distribution here:

http://abtester.com/calculator/

The method takes a zscore as input.  The results for me have have been similar to excel's NORMDIST.

```
function cumnormdist($x)
{
  $b1 =  0.319381530;
  $b2 = -0.356563782;
  $b3 =  1.781477937;
  $b4 = -1.821255978;
  $b5 =  1.330274429;
  $p  =  0.2316419;
  $c  =  0.39894228;

  if($x >= 0.0) {
      $t = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + $p * $x );
      return (1.0 - $c * exp( -$x * $x / 2.0 ) * $t *
      ( $t *( $t * ( $t * ( $t * $b5 + $b4 ) + $b3 ) + $b2 ) + $b1 ));
  }
  else {
      $t = 1.0 / ( 1.0 - $p * $x );
      return ( $c * exp( -$x * $x / 2.0 ) * $t *
      ( $t *( $t * ( $t * ( $t * $b5 + $b4 ) + $b3 ) + $b2 ) + $b1 ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! There are a few reasons I can't get the PECL stats package on my server, and this works perfectly to replace stats_cdf_normal($x, 0, 1, 1)

Comment: Useful since PECL stats is not supported in PHP 7 as of this writing (as far as I know). Anyway, the formula can be simplified a bit, as on this page (scroll down to php)  http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~goguen/courses/130/SayBlackScholes.html    Furthermore, it can be verified against   http://wps.aw.com/wps/media/objects/3853/3945845/ch15/table1.html

Comment: Btw, just for reference, I just added it in my repository https://github.com/shadiakiki1986/php-blackscholes with tests for a few values in the table I mention above