# PHP implementation of custom number distribution

Tags: php, math

I'm looking for a function to generate random numbers in `[a,b]`

Function must take one argument - seed and return random `x є [a,b]`.
The probability of `x = a` is the lowest, but is increasing when moving to b. The probability of `x = b` should be the highest.

As far as I understand what I'm looking for is an implementation of cumulative distribution function, but can't say for sure. So i'll be glad for direct literature. Or maybe there's an in-box php implementation already?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  If you do not show some code, folks will close this faster than you can blink.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304765/how-to-generate-a-cumulative-normal-distribution-in-php

Comment: I haven't tried coding yet... Can't imagine where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you did not specify what an argument should be.
The function below does not use comulative distribution. Incereasing the $n will cause values close to b more likely to be returned.

```
function almostRandom() {
    $a = 1;
    $b = 10;
    $n = 2.5;

    $random = rand(0, 1000000) / 1000000;

    $positionInInterval = 1 - pow($random, $n);

    $intervalLength = $b - $a;
    $value = $a + $intervalLength * $positionInInterval;

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: This actually works, but I can't understand it at all. The argument is a "seed" (just recently found out how it's called)... Thanks!

Comment: Use Wolfram Alpha to plot a graph of 1 - x^2.5 You will be able to see, that if x is random number between 0 and 1, the value of the graph is more likely to be closer to 1 than to 0.
You can set the seed for random generator with srand function http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php