# standard normal cumulative distribution function

Tags: php, function, math, plugins, probability

Is there a php function for the standard normal cumulative distribution function?

I can't find one.

A plugin/library is great too.

Please show me where it is.

Many thanks in advance!

**stats_cdf_normal**

Gives `Fatal error: Call to undefined function stats_cdf_normal()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an undocumented `stats_cdf_normal()` function in the [PECL stats package](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stats.php).

Check out the note at the bottom of this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.stats.php

> **oliver at •••••••• dot com:**
>
> There are some undocumented functions in this extension, eg I found the following by reading the DCDFLIB docs and some trial and error:

```
<?php

/**
 * stats_cdf_normal($x, $mean, $sd, 1)
 * @return float cumulative probablity
 */
echo stats_cdf_normal(1.96, 0, 1, 1) . "\n";

/**
 * stats_cdf_normal($p, $mean, $sd, 2)
 * @return float x which bounds cumulative probalility $p
 */
echo stats_cdf_normal(0.975, 0, 1, 2) . "\n";

// less useful
// echo stats_cdf_normal(0.4,0.5,0.6,3) . "\n";
// echo stats_cdf_normal(0.4,0.5,0.6,4) . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Good job. Us old guys can't keep up with you youngsters!

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy The function is in a PECL package, see edit. I installed it on my system and it appears to be working.

Comment: @WaleedKhan do you know which one?  i'm condemned to wampserver lol

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy See http://www.php.net/manual/en/stats.installation.php. Since you're on Windows you might have to build it from source, but it was a fairly painless process for me; the harder part was tracking down my `php.ini` to add the extension.

Comment: It seems that the PECL stats package is not available for PHP 7. When I try `pecl install stats`, I get the error `pecl/stats requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.6.99), installed version is 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3`. Any ideas? Maybe I should just use the estimator documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13361716/4126114

Comment: 2.0 is supposed to support php7 according to the changelog: https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=stats&release=2.0.3 You can probably run: pear install stats-2.0.3